# sort a list of percentages

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list:

```
l = ['50%','12.5%','6.25%','25%']
```

Which I would like to sort in the following order:

```
['6.25%','12.5%','25%','50%']
```

Using l.sort() yields:

```
['12.5%','25%','50%','6.25%']
```

Any cool tricks to sort these lists easily in Python?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Comment: Store the data as numbers not strings! - depends on what else you are doing with the data but needing one conversion to number on input and one on output might have less cost than several conversions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can sort with a custom key

```
b =['52.5%', '62.4%', '91.8%', '21.5%']
b.sort(key = lambda a: float(a[:-1]))
```

This resorts the set, but uses the numerical value as the key (i.e. chops of the '%' in the string and converts to float.

Comment: Sorry misprint. These things happen :)

Comment: Ahh, cool - it almost worked I had to do a:
b.sort(key = lambda a: float(str(a[:-1])))
To make it fully functional.

Comment: No no, check it again.  Sorry, in my half-asleep state I wrote 'str' instead of 'float.  Sorry about that :)